# Python libraries on Web Job

Tags: python, azure, anaconda, azure-webjobs

My goal is to run a Python script that uses Anaconda libraries (such as Pandas) on `Azure WebJob` but can't seem to figure out how to load the libraries.

I start out just by testing a simple Azure blob to blob file copy which works when run locally but hit into an error `"ImportError: No module named 'azure'"` when ran in WebJob.

example code:

```py
    from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
    blobAccountName = <name>
    blobStorageKey = <key>  
    containerName = <containername>
    blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name=blobAccountName,
    account_key=blobStorageKey)
    blobService.set_container_acl(containerName)   
    b = blobService.get_blob_to_bytes(containerName, 'file.csv')
    blobService.create_blob_from_bytes(containerName, 'file.csv', b.content)
```

I can't even get Azure SDK libraries to run. let alone Anaconda's

How do I run a python script that requires external libraries such as Anaconda (and even Azure SDK). How do I "pip install" these stuff for a WebJob?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you've kown about deployment of Azure WebJobs, I offer the below steps for you  to show how to load external libraries in python scripts.

Step 1 :
Use the **virtualenv** component to create an independent python runtime environment in your system.Please install it first with command `pip install virtualenv`  if you don't have it.

If you installed it successfully ,you could see it in your **python/Scripts** file.

[image]

Step2 : Run the commad to create independent python runtime environment.

[image]

Step 3: Then go into the created directory's **Scripts** folder and activate it (**this step is important , don't miss it**)

[image]

Please **don't close this command window** and use `pip install <your libraryname>` to download external  libraries in this command window.

[image]

Step 4：Keep the Sample.py uniformly compressed into a folder with the libs packages in the **Libs/site-packages** folder  that you rely on.

[image]

Step 5:
Create webjob in Web app service and upload the zip file,then you could execute your Web Job and check the log

[image]

You could also refer to the SO thread :[Options for running Python scripts in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716757/options-for-running-python-scripts-in-azure/45725327#45725327)

In addition, if you want to use the modules in Anaconda, please download them separately. There is no need to download the entire library.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for assisting!... I tried following your steps.. created a PythonSandbox in my G: drive... pip install Azure and zip it up. Unfortunately I still ran into an error, this time in D:\local\temp\jobs..i captured the image here [Inline Link](http://imgur.com/a/Gtj2D) :-(

Comment: @ianch It seems that the external libraries have been got in your WebJob, depend on the exception log info you provide, I could not find the specific error exception ,would you please show more details about the error logs?

Comment: @ianch According to the error log [No module named six], it is obvious that the external library is missing. Please use the command [pip install] to complete all the libraries that your code relayed on and upload again

Comment: I did a check and module six is installed. [LINK1](http://imgur.com/ihpqece) & [LINK2](http://imgur.com/jgrRdna) The code i have is as per above, just a blob copy. It does seems the error may have started from the import azure.storage.blob which again that module is already installed. Kind of puzzling..

Comment: I found out the issue!... Azure WebJob only supports 2.7 / 3.4 32-bit version... once I re-do the virtual env with the correct version, it works. [LINK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/08/04/upgrading-python-on-azure-app-service/) this link helped to explain the reason as well. Thanks Jay

Comment: I followed the instructions here to a T, and I can get it to work with a script that only uses the requests module, but when I try it with another one, I am getting the same error that:

"ImportError: No module named " ... 

I ran it with Python 3.4 32 bit just for this purpose and it's still not working. I'm out of ideas. Anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can point your Azure WebJob to your main WebApp environment (and thus its real site packages).  This allows you to use the newest fastest version of Python supported by the WebApp (right now mine is 364x64), much better than 3.4 or 2.7 in x86.  Another huge benefit is then you don't have to maintain an additional set of packages that are statically held in a file somewhere (this gave me a lot of trouble with dynamic libraries with crazy dependencies such as psycopg2 and pandas).

HOW: In your WebJobs files, set up a .cmd file that runs your run.py, and in that .cmd file, you can just have one line of code like this:

D:\home\python364x64\python.exe run.py

That's it!

Azure WebJobs looks at .cmd files first, then run.py and others.
See this link for an official MS post on this method:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/12/09/running-python-webjob-on-azure-app-services-using-non-default-python-version/