# Scheduling a python script on Azure

Tags: python, azure, scheduler

So I was looking into scheduling a python script on a daily basis and, rather than using Task Scheduler on my own machine, I was wondering if it is possible to do so using an Azure cloud account.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your needs, I suggest you use **Web Jobs** in Web Apps Service.

It has two types of Azure Web Jobs for you to choose: 
**Continuous** and **Trigger**.
For your needs, **Trigger** should be adopted.

You could refer to the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-webjobs-resources) for more details.In addition, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) shows how to run tasks in WebJobs.

You could refer to the steps as below to create your webjob.

***Step 1*** :
Use the **virtualenv** component to create an independent python runtime environment in your system.Please install it first with command `pip install virtualenv`  if you don't have it.

If you installed it successfully ,you could see it in your **python/Scripts** file.

[image]

***Step2*** : Run the commad to create independent python runtime environment.

[image]

***Step 3***: Then go into the created directory's **Scripts** folder and activate it (**this step is important , don't miss it**)

[image]

Please **don't close this command window** and use `pip install <your libraryname>` to download external  libraries in this command window.

[image]

***Step 4***：Keep the Webjob.py(which is your own business code) uniformly compressed into a folder with the libs packages in the **Libs/site-packages** folder  that you rely on.

[image]

***Step 5***:
Create webjob in Web app service and upload the zip file,then you could execute your Web Job and check the log

[image]

You could also refer to the SO thread:

1.[Options for running Python scripts in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716757/options-for-running-python-scripts-in-azure/45725327#45725327)

2.[Python libraries on Web Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860272/python-libraries-on-web-job/45873655#45873655)

BTW,you need to create a azure web app first because Webjob runs in azure web app.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I started with this provided answer but the free tier didn't provide the functionality I needed (Python + scheduled trigger).

I switched to a serverless Azure Function in Python with a timer trigger to get the required functionality. Tutorial, use timer trigger instead of http trigger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-01

Comment: Python web app service [can only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli%2Cvscode-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli) be deployed on a linux virtual machine in azure. And Web Jobs are [not available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#overview) on linux.