# Using Python-Package in Azure WebJobs showing Eror - ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python-2.7, azure, azure-webjobs

I am working on Creating azure WebJobs using the python script.This requires package like azure-storage-blob and pandas. In order to use the packages, I followed the instruction given on the links  [Python libraries on Web Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860272/python-libraries-on-web-job) and  https://lnx.azurewebsites.net/python-site-packages-in-azure-python-webjobs/.

## Error

> [03/13/2018 05:30:00 > a941f1: SYS INFO] Status changed to
>   Initializing [03/13/2018 05:30:02 > a941f1: SYS INFO] Job directory
>   change detected: Job file 'some\site-packages\six.pyc' timestamp
>   differs between source and working directories. [03/13/2018 05:30:36 >
>   a941f1: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.cmd' with script host -
>   'WindowsScriptHost' [03/13/2018 05:30:36 > a941f1: SYS INFO] Status
>   changed to Running [03/13/2018 05:30:36 > a941f1: INFO]  [03/13/2018
>   05:30:36 > a941f1: INFO]
>   D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\blobs\okznsh2a.kix\some>D:\home\Python27\python.exe
>   blob.py  [03/13/2018 05:30:38 > a941f1: ERR ] Traceback (most recent
>   call last): [03/13/2018 05:30:38 > a941f1: ERR ]   File "blob.py",
>   line 4, in  [03/13/2018 05:30:38 > a941f1: ERR ]     from
>   azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService,ContentSettings [03/13/2018
>   05:30:38 > a941f1: ERR ]   File
>   "site-packages\azure\storage\blob__init__.py", line 6, in 
>   [03/13/2018 05:30:38 > a941f1: ERR ]     from .appendblobservice
>   import AppendBlobService [03/13/2018 05:30:38 > a941f1: ERR ]   File
>   "site-packages\azure\storage\blob\appendblobservice.py", line 30, in
>    [03/13/2018 05:30:38 > a941f1: ERR ]     from
>   ._deserialization import ( [03/13/2018 05:30:38 > a941f1: ERR ]   File
>   "site-packages\azure\storage\blob_deserialization.py", line 39, in
>    [03/13/2018 05:30:38 > a941f1: ERR ]     from ._encryption
>   import _decrypt_blob [03/13/2018 05:30:38 > a941f1: ERR ]   File
>   "site-packages\azure\storage\blob_encryption.py", line 13, in
>    [03/13/2018 05:30:38 > a941f1: ERR ]     from
>   cryptography.hazmat.primitives.padding import PKCS7 [03/13/2018
>   05:30:38 > a941f1: ERR ]   File
>   "site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\padding.py", line 13, in
>    [03/13/2018 05:30:38 > a941f1: ERR ]     from
>   cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding import lib [03/13/2018 05:30:38
>
> > a941f1: ERR ] ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. [03/13/2018 05:30:38 > a941f1: SYS INFO] Status
> >     changed to Failed [03/13/2018 05:30:38 > a941f1: SYS ERR ] Job failed
> >     due to exit code 1

I looked for ImportError: DLL load failed in Azure but I did not get any convincing answer associated with this problem.Most of them associated with upgrading some package.The folder that I am using to upload for the Webjobs has the following things

```
blob.py
run.cmd
site-packages
```

## Files

#### run.cmd contains:

```
D:\home\Python27\python.exe blob.py
```

#### blob.py

```
enter code here
import sys
sys.path.append("site-packages")
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService,ContentSettings
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
class blobfunction:
        def __init__(self,account,key):

            self.block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account, account_key=key)
```

How do I run the azure Webjobs using the blob.py script?

Comment: Hi,any progress now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested similar code on my side and the webjobs works well for me.

Depending on the path you provide, I can see that you are installing the `Python27` extension in your webapp.

I installed python `2.7.14*86` version and installed `azure-storage` package via pip.

[image]

***run.cmd:***

```
D:\home\Python27\python.exe sample.py
```

***sample.py:***(There is no need to add a path here because the dependent packages are installed in the default path which set in the above cmd)

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService,ContentSettings

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='***', account_key='***')

generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs('jay')
for blob in generator:
    print "\t Blob name: " , blob.name
```

Run the webjob:

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: great so you mean we need upload mydemo.py file into python dir and in webjob we need to upload run.cmd file with python exe path like `D:\home\python364x64\python.exe mydemo.py` is it right?