# Import module into Python Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to make a simple Azure Function that receives an HTTP event, grabs a JSON object in the body of that request, and saves that object as a document in a CosmosDB collection. I seem to be getting hung up on importing a python module however.

**__init__.py**

```
import json
import azure.functions as func
import azure.cosmos.cosmos_client as cosmos_client


config = {
  'ENDPOINT': 'https://XXXXXX.documents.azure.com:443/',
  'PRIMARYKEY': 'XXXXXX',
  'DATABASE': 'my-database',
  'CONTAINER': 'my-container'
}

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
  try:
    client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(config['ENDPOINT'], {'masterKey': config['PRIMARYKEY']})
    results = req.get_json()

    client.get_database_client(config['DATABASE']).get_container_client(config['CONTAINER']).upsert_item(results)

    return func.HttpResponse("Success", status_code=200)
  except ValueError:
    return func.HttpResponse("Please pass a JSON object", status_code=400)
```

*Error Log*

```
019-07-11T22:51:22.613140092Z: [INFO]  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.save-to-cosmos ---> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Rpc.RpcException: Result: Failure
2019-07-11T22:51:22.616516971Z: [INFO]  Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cosmos'
2019-07-11T22:51:22.616547173Z: [INFO]  Stack:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 230, in _handle__function_load_request
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632613023Z: [INFO]      func_request.metadata.entry_point)
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632631824Z: [INFO]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/functions_worker/loader.py", line 66, in load_function
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632637524Z: [INFO]      mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632641725Z: [INFO]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632646025Z: [INFO]      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632650325Z: [INFO]    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632655025Z: [INFO]    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632660926Z: [INFO]    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632682827Z: [INFO]    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632688427Z: [INFO]    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632692727Z: [INFO]    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632697128Z: [INFO]    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632723529Z: [INFO]    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632729029Z: [INFO]    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632733329Z: [INFO]    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632737430Z: [INFO]    File "/home/site/wwwroot/save-to-cosmos/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
2019-07-11T22:51:22.632741830Z: [INFO]      import azure.cosmos.cosmos_client as cosmos_client
```

I have tried going through Kudu like this question suggested [Importing Python modules for Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965193/importing-python-modules-for-azure-function) and tried running `pip install azure-cosmos` but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: [**This**](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/tree/master/v2functions/cosmos-trigger-cosmodb-output-binding#publish-the-function-to-the-cloud) will help. Also make sure you have a `requirements.txt` for your Python dependencies in the root of your function app (where `hosts.json` and `local.settings.json` sit). To develop and run locally you'll need to activate a Python Virtual Environment - see [**this**](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/docs/quickstart-v2-python-functions.md#create-and-activate-a-virtual-environment).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add python extension in your Function App KUDU.

**Step1**: To Install Custom Python Version

Navigate to Kudu Console - `https://Your_APP_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`
Run Below command in kudu cli to install Python in D:\home\site\tools Folder

nuget.exe install -Source https://www.siteextensions.net/api/v2/ -OutputDirectory D:\home\site\tools python352x64

**Step2**: We need to have python.exe in `D:\home\site\tools Folder`. so lets move sub-folder content(`D:\home\site\tools\python352x64.3.5.2.6\content\Python35`
) to `D:\home\site\tools` using below command

```
mv /d/home/site/tools/python352x64.3.5.2.6/content/python35/* /d/home/site/tools/
```

**Step3**: To Install custom python package.

Navigate to Kudu Console - https://Your_APP_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole
Run below command to install pandas module in function app:

```
D:\home\site\tools\python.exe -m pip install azure-cosmos
```

***Test example:***

I installed `requests` package to do a little test.

```
 D:\home\site\tools\python.exe -m pip install requests
```

[image]

**python code:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I should've mentioned I'm using Bash, do you have the equivalent for my setup?

Comment: @RyanGrush Bash steps are listed in the official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python#run-the-function-locally. You need to activate a virtual environment locally and use pip install package. Then deploy it into azure env.

Comment: @RyanGrush Hi,any updates now? does my answer helps you?

Comment: It looks like the problem was using "Deployment Center" linked to my ADO repo which was causing the problem. Publishing a function app directly works but linking it to an ADO repo expects a pipeline in place I'm assuming.

Comment: @JayGong can you please help me on this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71951268/azure-function-python-module-compatibility-issue`