# When deploying python Azure function on azure get No module found error

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have created a Python Azure HttpTrigger function also executed on the local. It works fine on local but when I am deploying Azure HttpTrigger function on azure then I got below error:-

```
There was an error restoring dependencies. ERROR: cannot install pyodbc-4.0.25 dependency: binary dependencies without wheels are not supported. 
Use the --build-native-deps option to automatically build and configure the dependencies using a Docker container. More information at https://aka.ms/func-python-publish
```

I have added the Pyodbc package in `requirement.txt file`. When python azure functions deploying on azure that time pyodbc installed on the local python path not in .env path.

I have already selected the python interpreter `\.env\Scripts\python.ext` but pyodbc package installs on the local python path.

I am not able to understand how can I solve above problem? If anybody knows the solution please let me know.  I want to install packages on azure funcions.

Comment: Try posting it in Github for Azure functions - https://github.com/azure/azure-functions/issues

Comment: Please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/640#issuecomment-414784079).

Comment: @GeorgeChen I have already tried it, but it didn't work.  Is the any other solution.

Comment: @GeorgeChen whenever i am used external package in python azure functions then that time i got deployment error.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you confused about how to install and use Python third-party module in the Azure function app. You could refer to my working steps.

Step 1 :

Navigate to your function app kudu url : `https://Your_APP_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.

Run below command in `d:/home/site/wwwroot/<your function name>` folder (will take some time)

```
python -m virtualenv myvenv
```

Step 2 :

Load the env via the below command in `env/Scripts` folder.

```
activate.bat
```

Step 3 :

Your shell should be now prefixed by (env).

Update pip

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Install what you need

```
python -m pip install MySQLdb <pyodbc>
```

Step 4 :

In your code, update the sys.path to add this venv:

```
import sys, os.path
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), 'env/Lib/site-packages')))
```

Then connect to mysql db via the snippet of code below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

# Connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="appuser",
                     passwd="",
                     db="onco")

cursor = db.cursor()

# Execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM location")

# Commit your changes if writing
# In this case, we are only reading data
# db.commit()

# Get the number of rows in the resultset
numrows = cursor.rowcount

# Get and display one row at a time
for x in range(0, numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print row[0], "-->", row[1]

# Close the connection
db.close()
```

In addition, you could also refer to my previous case: [Import module into Python Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56998307/import-module-into-python-azure-function/56999251#56999251).