# Azure Function Python Module compatibility issue

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am developing an Azure function using `Python`. This function is going to write some data to blob storage. This function having dependencies on couple of azure modules.

1. `azure-functions`
2. `azure-storage-blob`
   **The problem is:** The function is unable to detect the libraries though It is installed properly and available in functions virtual environment.
   Also, I have observed that if I install the first `azure-functions` and after that `azure-storage-blob` then import statement `from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient` unable to detect the module but `import azure.functions as func` will work, but if I interchange the installation sequence then the `import azure.functions as func` would get detected but `from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient` remain unrecognized and will show the error as `Import "azure.storage.blob" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)`. So clearly it is a module version conflict.
   I am not sure which version I should use hence seeking the help from the community warriors. Thanks !
   **Note**: I am using python 3.8.2 for the development purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not install modules one by one manually.**
Apply the following steps:

**1)** Remove the existing virtual environment.
**2)** Create a new virtual environment.
`python -m venv C:\Users\UserName\FunctionApp\.venv`
**3)** It may be required to enable the Activate.ps1 (VS Code updates the virtual environment path itself)
`& c:/Users/UserName/FunctionApp/.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1`
**4)** Put the details of the modules in the requirements.txt file.
**5)** Debug or run the code. This process itself download the necessary packages.

Now everything is ready. Every import statement would be able to detect the respective modules.

Answer (score 0):

You might be facing this issue due to virtual environment configuration and the module is not getting installed in the right file path.

**Points to check:**

1. Make sure your virtual environment is active. For more information on how to activate your virtual environment you can refer [How to Create virtual environment in Python](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-create-requirements-txt-file-in-python#:%7E:text=In%20Python%20requirement.,Typically%20this%20file%20%22requirement)
2. All the modules need to be installed to the < Your_Virtual_Environment>/lib/site-packages directory.
3. Make sure you are upgrading pip to the latest `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.
4. If you receive the below suggestion try accepting so that you can avoid the above steps but just upgrade pip to latest and install `azure-blob-storage`.

   [image]

After following above steps we could able to use both `import azure.functions as func` and `from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient`.

[image]